# Sub-schema properties are not updated mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

little bit stuck with one issue which is related to mongoose. I have a Project schema with sub-schema(SingleUserSchema). Whenever I add a new User to this schema it saves everything and that's ok. The issue is that if I update the user, old values in schema does not update. Any ideas how to solve this case? Stuck here for a whole day already.

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SingleUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Provide project name'],
      minlength: 5,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Provide description about the project'],
    },
    maxWorkingEmployees: {
      type: Number,
      required: [
        true,
        'Provide maximum number of employees working on this project',
      ],
    },
    currentlyWorkingEmployees: [SingleUserSchema],
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Pending', 'In progress', 'Paused', 'Delayed', 'Completed'],
      default: 'Pending',
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

Controller:

```
  const attachEmployeeToProject = async (req, res) => {
  const { projectId, userId } = req.params;

  const project = await Project.findOne({ _id: projectId });
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId });

  if (!user) {
    throw new NotFoundError(`User with id ${userId} does not exists`);
  }

  if (!project) {
    throw new NotFoundError(`Project with id ${userId} does not exists`);
  }

  const { role, email, status } = user;
  const SingleUserSchema = {
    email,
    role,
    status,
  };

  let currentlyWorkingEmployees = [
    ...project.currentlyWorkingEmployees,
    SingleUserSchema,
  ];
  req.body.currentlyWorkingEmployees = currentlyWorkingEmployees;

  const updateProject = await Project.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: projectId },
    req.body,
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    }
  );
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ updateProject });
};
```

Maybe I just simply need to create a reference? Tried like this and received tons of errors, also felt lost how to create n references in array.

```
 currentlyWorkingEmployees: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    ],
```

User schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide username'],
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide username'],
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: 'Please provide valid email address',
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide password'],
    validator: {
      validate: {
        validator: validator.isStrongPassword,
        message: 'Please provide stronger password',
      },
    },
  },
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide first name'],
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide last name'],
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Working', 'Pause', 'Offline'],
    default: 'Offline',
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'Developer',
      'Analyst',
      'Designer',
      'Architect',
      'Project Manager',
      'Owner',
      'Teamleader',
      'Employee',
    ],
    default: 'Employee',
  },
  verificationToken: {
    type: String,
  },
  isTokenVerified: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  tokenValidationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: null,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as far as I see you don't have a model called 'User' so that's the reason why your reference is not working.

```
    currentlyWorkingEmployees: [
        { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    ]
```

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Second, you need to identify the user you want to update (based on userId) inside currentlyWorkingEmployees collection, if I understood correctly your problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I haven't shared User model here, however I do have it. My point is that whenever I create a user and attach it to project and later when I update user I still see old values at the project about the user.

Comment: I have uploaded the User schema